# Multiplication of two int's gets negative

Tags: java, int, download-manager

I'm currently coding a little download manager and I get a funny output when I try to calculate the download-progress in percent. This is what i use to calculate it:

```
int progress = (byte_counter * 100) / size;
System.out.println("("+byte_counter+" * 100) = "+(byte_counter * 100)
  +" / "+size+" = "+progress);
```

`byte-counter` is an int (it counts the total bytes read from the `InputStream`) and `size` is the length of the downloaded file in bytes.

This works great with small downloads. But when i get to bigger files (40MB) it starts making funny things. The Output for the calculation looks like this:

```
[...]
(21473280 * 100) = 2147328000 / 47659008 = 45
(21474720 * 100) = 2147472000 / 47659008 = 45
(21476160 * 100) = -2147351296 / 47659008 = -45
(21477600 * 100) = -2147207296 / 47659008 = -45
[...]
```

I don't know why, but the calculation gets negative. <strike>Since an normal Integer should be fine with numbers till 2<sup>31</sup>-1, this shouldn't be the problems root.</strike> But what am I missing?

Comment: Er, rather, a normal integer should be fine with numbers up to `2^31-1`, or `2,147,483,647`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_overflow

To fix in java, try using a `long` instead.

```
int progress = (int) ((byte_counter * 100L) / size);
```

or reverse order of operations

```
int progress = (int) (((float) byte_counter) / size) * 100);
```

Comment: I tried that, the problem is, that the result of the first calculation `(byte_counter * 100)` is never saved in any variable (should just be in memory). So I'm not sure where to specify the used data type.

Comment: @Lucas, the `100L` notation above specifies a `long` value of 100.  This will cause `byte_counter` to be promoted to a `long` before the multiplication happens.  In general, you can always force `byte_counter` to be promoted to a `long` by doing `((long) byte_counter)`.

Answer (score 5):

`21476160 * 100 = 2 147 616 000` is greater than `2 147 483 647`, the max int.

You're overflowing.

Use `long` for your calculations.

Answer (score 3):

```
2^31-1 = 2147483647  < 21476160 * 100 = 2147616000
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a long -- 2147760000 in binary is 10000000 00000100 00110111 10000000 and since the most significant bit is 1 it is interpreted as a negative number.